# How to Report Upload Progress to Google Cloud Storage in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Node.js to upload files to Google Cloud Storage and need to implement a way to report the upload progress to the users. I've been using the @google-cloud/storage library for handling file uploads but haven't found a clear solution for tracking and reporting upload progress. Does the library provide any hooks or events that I can listen to for progress updates? If so, how can I integrate them into my existing file upload code? Any code snippets or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
router.post("/upload-file", multer.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
    try{

        const folderPath = `Files/`;
        const blob = retmBucket.file(folderPath + req.file.originalname);
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();

        // TO DO
        blobStream.on('data', () => {
            // console.log(progress);
        });
        // =================
        

        blobStream.on("error", (error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Error during file upload!",
                error: error.message
            });
        });
        
        blobStream.on("finish", async () => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "File has been uploaded sucessfully",
                data: fileName
            })
        })

        blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);

        }catch{
        res.status(409).json({
            message: "Error during file upload!"
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem using ReadableStreamBuffer

I hope my solution helps!

```
router.post("/upload-file", multer.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
    try{

        const folderPath = `Files/`;
        const blob = retmBucket.file(folderPath + req.file.originalname);
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();

        const fileSize = req.file.size; // Total size of the file
        let uploadedBytes = 0;

        // Pipe the file buffer to the blob stream
        const fileBufferStream = new ReadableStreamBuffer();
        fileBufferStream.put(req.file.buffer);
        fileBufferStream.stop();

        fileBufferStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            uploadedBytes += chunk.length;
            progress = ((uploadedBytes / fileSize) * 100).toFixed(2);
            console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
        });

        fileBufferStream.pipe(blobStream)
        .on("error", (error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Error during file upload!",
                error: error.message
            });
        })
        .on("finish", async () => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "File has been uploaded sucessfully",
                data: fileName
            })
        });


        }catch{
        res.status(409).json({
            message: "Error during file upload!"
        })
    }
})
```